# Magit connecting to github with alternate ssh key

Tags: magit, ssh

I have two github accounts – one personal and one for my job. In most of my repos, I use my work account and magit works fine. In a couple personal repos, I have this in `.git/config`:

```
sshCommand = ssh -i /my/home/directory/.ssh/personal/id_rsa -F /dev/null
```

This works well from the command line for things like `git push`, but when I try to push from magit, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Permission to <personalaccount>/unified_docs_switcher.git denied to <workaccount>.
```

Since my work account is mentioned in the error message, it seems like magit's connection to git is ignoring the line in `.git/config`.

Is there some other config I can add to magit to recognize this?

Is there a different/better solution in magit to using different github accounts?

(Edit: emacs 27.1 on MacOS from [here](https://emacsformacosx.com/), tested on magit 2.90.1 from melpa-stable and then 20210105.1030 from melpa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pure Git solution you can use in your global `.gitconfig` - I use an `include.path` config for personal stuff by default:

```
# .gitconfig
# default user email and key
[include]
        path = .gitconfig-personal
```

and that file contains name, personal email (which is used for SSH and identifying my GitHub account), and GPG key ID:

```
# .gitconfig-personal
[user]
    name = jidicula
    email = "johanan@forcepush.tech"
    signingkey = "<personalKeyID>"
```

Then, below that first `[include]` in my global `.gitconfig`, I have an `includeIf.path` work config to use if the repo matches a pattern provided as an argument to `includeIf`:

```
# .gitconfig
# When working with Work
[includeIf "gitdir:**/work/**/.git"]
        path = .gitconfig-work
```

and that file contains name, work email, and work email GPG key ID:

```
# .gitconfig-work
[user]
        name = jidicula
        email = "johanan@work.email"
        signingkey = "<workKeyID>"
```

Anything in this second config will overwrite whatever was defined by default - paired with the conditional `includeIf`, we get path-dependent Git config.

Putting the global `.gitconfig` all together, we get:

```
# .gitconfig
# default user email and key
[include]
        path = .gitconfig-personal
# When working with Work
[includeIf "gitdir:**/work/**/.git"]
        path = .gitconfig-work
```

Then you'd fill `.gitconfig-personal` and `gitconfig-work` with your context-specific configs like emails, keys, usernames, pull behaviour, commit message templates, etc.

You can read more about conditional includes [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer. I'll give that a try when I get the chance!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help!